# How to create this arc with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to create this shape in CSS3?

[image]

The image should be a square image.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried alot, this is not just regular CSS.

I already tried googling on 'Arc' or any similar keyword.

This is the full image:
[image]

Thing is, it should stretch to full width. I tried implementing it as an image, but when you resize over 1400px the image becomes ugly, would be awesome if I could fix this with just CSS.

Comment: tried anything? your code please.

Comment: [Border-radius](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) is the answer.

Comment: can u provide a source from where you got this?

Comment: Why does everyone use SO as a search engine, but without actually using the internal search engine? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+border+css

Comment: Duplicate to at least 500 SO search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+border+css

Comment: Samples - [css3shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/)

Comment: I tried alot, this is not just regular CSS. 

I already tried googling on 'Arc' or any similar keyword.

This is the full image:
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A7z9y.png

Thing is, it should stretch to full width. I tried implementing it as an image, but when you resize over 1400px the image becomes ugly, would be awesome if I could fix this with just CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as by the comment it's quite simple!

If you use an HTML structure like that:

```
<div class="arcborder">
  <img src=""/>
  <div class="colorborder"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply manage the css in that way:

```
.arcborder{
width:800px;
height:450px;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:600px/80px;
}
.effectborder img{
margin-top:30px;
width:800px;
height:400px;
border-radius:600px/40px;
}
```

And you are done! [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/QZdMM/2/)

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thanks for your post. Thing is, now the top of the images also gets cut' off.

I tried fixing it but I'm not a hero with CSS3 borders. Is it possible to disable to top-left and top-right borders?